# Navigating to different jsp pages from menu bar in Liferay

Tags: jsp, liferay, liferay-6, menubar

I have created a menu bar using html, css, lists etc. in Liferay.

The option on it are Home, Reports, User etc. When I click on each of them a sub menu appears.

here is an example.
I have a menu bar with Home, Reports, User, Add and when I click on say Reports a sub menu appears which has Legal,Documents,Personal,Company.
When I click on any of them the jsp page should appear. Ex. If I click on Reports and select Personal then `Personal.jsp` page should appear but it is not happening in my case.

The `menubar.jsp` has links to pages. ex:

```
<li>
    <a href="#">Reports</a>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="../admin/Legal.jsp">Legal</a></li>
        <li><a href="../admin/Documents.jsp">Documents</a></li>
        <li><a href="../admin/Personal.jsp">Personal</a></li>
        <li><a href="../admin/Company.jsp">Company</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

When I try to access it the error that I am seeing is:

> The webpage at `http://localhost:8080/admin/Personal.jsp` might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new web address.

Although my path is correct I get the above error. Also when I use:

```
<a href="../admin/Personal.jsp">Personal</a>
```

I am redirected to the same page. Instead  When I use:

```
<a href="/admin/Personal.jsp">Personal</a>
```

I get the error mentioned above.

What is the solution?

Comment: i guess you can access your jsp page like this "<a href="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/admin/Legal.jsp">Legal</a>" also you can create your own page using liferay add page option..FYI

Comment: @Lucky Boy:
No it isn't working. In fact I get the following error:
type Exception report

message

description The server encountered an internal error () that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page /admin/Legal.jsp at line 66
This shoudn't happen since The Legal.jsp works properly..

Comment: do you have same error for all your jsp pages or only in Legal.jsp?

Comment: @Lucky Boy:
Thanks for the prompt replies. I got errors when I started using <%=request.getContextPath()%>   for all the jsp pages I am trying to get from menu bars

Comment: Are you building a portlet that should show its content with the given jsp files or do you run in a portal and then want to link to full-page jsps outside of your portal? In a portal world you cannot just link to some JSP. The solution inside of a portal depends quite a bit on what framework you implement your portlet with. With Liferay MVC you'd link to `<a href="<portlet:renderURL><portlet:param name="mvcPath" value="/admin/Personal.jsp"/></portlet:renderURL>">Personal</a>`

Comment: @Olaf Kock:
Thanks Olaf.. " In a portal world you cannot just link to some JSP". I agree but I didnt know how to go on.. Your suggestion worked.. Can you  make this as your answer so I can accept it...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Converted the comment to an answer, you're welcome :)

Are you building a portlet that should show its content with the given jsp files or do you run in a portal and then want to link to full-page jsps outside of your portal? In a portal world you cannot just link to some JSP. The solution inside of a portal depends quite a bit on what framework you implement your portlet with. With Liferay MVC you'd link to

```
<a href="<portlet:renderURL>
            <portlet:param name="mvcPath" value="/admin/Personal.jsp"/>
         </portlet:renderURL>">Personal</a>
```

and the portlet you're implementing will automatically display this page as its content.